# PHP Oist two variables from one dropdown menu into Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am creating a maintenance log entry form. The user is required to select from the drop down menu their name. The database will then hold in that row a record of who carried out the maintenance.

One table I have "engineers" which has id,name,department columns. The table I'm posting into is "log" which has id,department,engineer...etc.

When the form is posted that dropdown inserts the engineers id into "log" but I want it to be able to insert (without adding another field/dropdown) the corresponding department.

Here's my code:

```
    <label>Engineer Name:</label>
<br/><br/>
<select id="engineer" name="engineer">
 <?php
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=frontier_maintlog', 'frontier_admin', 'Lys100p*');
        #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
        $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select id,name,department from engineers');
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
            echo "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[name]</option>";
        }
  ?>
 </select> 

<br/><br/>

<input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit"/><br />
```

Hope it makes sense, i confused myself a little typing that!

Answer (score 0):

Department shouldn't be in the same table as engineers, as you will have double data; you want to avoid that in MySQL.
So you should have these tables:

ENGINEERS (IDe, name,IDd (external key pointing to the department table)
DEPARTMENT (IDd, department_name)
LOG (IDl, message, ..., IDe (external key pointing to the engineers table)

What you wanna do then is fill the log table with the current maintenance job, pointing only at the engineers table. The department name here is useless, as there's a table dedicated to that (and you can use the external Key in ENGINEERS to find which department the engineer belongs to).

Hopefully this makes sense to you!

Comment: That's exactly what I have I have a foreign key restraint which links the column department in table engineers to table "department" sorry i forgot to mention that. I'm not duplicating data.
That does make sense, i suppose I can use logical statement in the backend to return the corresponding department. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the question how to send in more values from the form?

If so one option is to use `<option value='$row[id]-$row['department]'>$row[name]</option>` and then when reading the data you split the value into id and department using `$values = explode('-', $_POST['engineer']` where id is in `$values[0]` and department in `$values[1]`

Another option is to select department from engineers when inserting the data, `INSERT INTO ... (select department from engineers where id = ?` and bind to `$_POST['engineer']`

You should later look into normalization of the database and separating models from the view